# Python - Cannot Open .docx when I wrote a new line to it

Tags: python, macos, file, ms-word

Just learning how to use files in python. I created a word document "mydoc.docx", opens properly before I execute the code below:

```
myfile = open('mydoc.docx','w')
myfile.write ("hello"+'\n')
myfile.close()
```

After I ran the code above, the word document cannot be opened any more showing "Word experienced an error trying to open the file."

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Microsoft Word is going to make assumptions about the format of a file based on the file's extension.  What you are writing out will produce something that is not in DOCX format.  Word is expecting to see that format, and will barf when it doesn't find it.  Change the extension on the file you are writing to `.txt` and you'll have better luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected.  A "docx" has a very specific structure (under the covers, it's a series of zipped files) that includes the text of the document, plus formatting, metadata, change history, etc.

What you have written with your Python program is a plain text file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be that python with `open()` function, opens `.docx` files as binary or plain text file (however definetly not a .docx file), and by writing data to it, you actually corrupt it.

It would be better if you would use libraries that can proccess `.docx` files. For example: [docx library](https://pypi.org/project/docx/0.2.4/)

Answer (score 0):

`myfile = open('mydoc.docx','w')`

You are not opening the file in append mode. What you're doing here is clearing the file completely & then writing new text to it.
You'll also want to be using the binary mode for opening files like this.

Further, even if you do append text to the file's contents, it's very unlikely that you'll see your appended text in the file when you open it up.

A good thing to get into a habit of doing is checking file sizes when diagnosing problems like this. If you checked the file size it would be 6 or 7 bytes I imagine. `docx` files are much, much bigger.